# Extending the vocabulary on deployment

Tags: python, pytorch, torchtext

When doing training, I initialize my embedding matrix, using the pretrained embeddings picked for words in training set vocabulary.

```
import torchtext as tt
contexts = tt.data.Field(lower=True, sequential=True, tokenize=tokenizer, use_vocab=True)
contexts.build_vocab(data, vectors="fasttext.en.300d",
                         vectors_cache=config["vectors_cache"])
```

In my model I pass contexts.vocab as parameter and initialize embeddings:

```
embedding_dim = vocab.vectors.shape[1]
self.embeddings = nn.Embedding(len(vocab), embedding_dim)
self.embeddings.weight.data.copy_(vocab.vectors)
self.embeddings.weight.requires_grad=False
```

I train my model and during training I save its 'best' state via `torch.save(model, f)`.

Then I want to test/create demo for model in separate file for evaluation. I load the model via `torch.load`. How do I extend the embedding matrix to contain test vocabulary? I tried to replace embedding matrix

```
# data is TabularDataset with test data
contexts.build_vocab(data, vectors="fasttext.en.300d",
                     vectors_cache=config["vectors_cache"])

model.embeddings = torch.nn.Embedding(len(contexts.vocab), contexts.vocab.vectors.shape[1])
model.embeddings.weight.data.copy_(contexts.vocab.vectors)
model.embeddings.weight.requires_grad = False
```

But the results are terrible (almost 0 accuracy). Model was doing good during training. What is the 'correct way' of doing this?

Comment: You can't. You have to have a predefined vocabulary before training itself.

Comment: But I am not training the embedding itself. I don't see why would I need such words in the torch.nn.Embedding, that will never get used. That just takes precious GPU memory. There must be a way to replace the embeddings.